# Core Data Where clause between two tables?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have two tables that I would like to get data and from by seeing if they match a particular attribute.

I want to write a predicate or something like this but I do not seem to be able to come up with a solution: `@"Data.item == Item.code"`.

The reason why I don't use relationships is because my database was imported from mysql. So all the data is coming from outside of the app its being synced from downloaded mysql tables.

---------------------------EDIT-------------------------
What I have tried so far lots of things here is the crappy way I am doing this now perhaps from this you can understand more of what I am trying to do .

```
 NSPredicate * Newpredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hid == 2"];
    NSArray *row2 = [db DLook:Newpredicate table:@"Data"];
    for (NSManagedObject *data in row2) {
        NSLog(@"\n\n\n\nid\n\n\n\n: %@", [data valueForKey:@"id"]);
        NSString *itemToCode = [data valueForKey:@"item"];
        NSPredicate *itemPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"code == %@",itemToCode];
        NSArray *itemRow = [db DLook:itemPredicate table:@"Item"];
        for (NSManagedObject *item in itemRow) {
            NSLog(@"\n\n\n\ncode : %@\n\n\n\n",[item valueForKey:@"code"]);
        }
       // NSLog(@"id: %@", [data valueForKey:@"id"]);
        //NSManagedObject * itemhid= [data valueForKey:@"testRel"];
        //NSLog(@"code: %@",[itemhid valueForKey:@"code"]);
    }
    NSLog(@"\n\n\n\n%d\n\n\n\n",[row2 count]);
```

The DLook is a convince method that just fetches the data using the predicate on the table that I pass.  Then take the returned area of NSmanaged objects looping through them.

I wish I could just make a magical relationship that would let me get a all the Item.data that match the Data.items!!! 
I don't want to do it like this I want to make a relationship that would work like that.

Help 
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you share some code or the model? What about that specific attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your equality in the predicate would only be true if the two objects are actually the same object. You could do this:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"item = %@", code];
```

However, you should really try to get the relationships right when importing your model. Then you would not even have to do a fetch from the store but just use

```
dataObject.item;
```

So, when you import do something like this:

```
// get one data object from your source
// get the corresponding item object from your source
Data *dataObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Data"
     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
Item *itemObject = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Item"
     inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
[dataObject addItemObject:itemObject];
```

Comment: That is the problem and what I need help with.... how to set the relationships right????

Comment: I expanded my answer to help you with the import step.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But there is a problem I am not inserting objects like this.

Comment: My data is coming from imported mysql tables that and this is done table by table.  This is why I can not use your standard way of doing things.  My data is saved row by row as it is imported from the mysql tables.

Comment: Does this mean i can't use relationships in core data.  You can't set up relationships after the fact???

Comment: No you can do the import as I showed you. Your objections have nothing to do with the problem. When importing "table by table" just import the data table (with `insertNewObject...`), then for each item in the items table do the second step in my answer.

Comment: The class does not just handle those two it does any mysql table and imports it into any entity who's properties match the fields.  Its modular and I would like to keep it that way.
I wish I could do it that way.... but I can't.  
So I am trying how to figure out how to set a relationship on preexisting data not the background ids that core data creates in the background.  But there is no apparent way of doing this ;( So thats why I was asking you guys.

Comment: I told you above how to do it, by doing a separate fetch.

Comment: OK supposing I do the import like you said.... how is core data going to know that I want to get the item object that corresponds with data.item and item.code... I just don't see how to make that distinction.  you say to do --  dataObject.item;  =--- but how would core data know that I want the dataObject.item that equals == itemObject.code.  This is the million dollar question that I am trying to wrap my head around.  If you could just explain how I might do that then I can mark this as answered.  Once again I appreciate your patience.

Comment: So does this mean that when I do the import I have to import using the rule data.item == item.code... so that I have a "set" or save the object context with these two connected from the start?????
what if I have other ways in other fields I want to connect data????

Comment: In other words have a lot of other tables that use item.code to connect to but they are not necessarily all one to ones so .... I don't want to make my import overly complicated... I was hoping there was an elegant way to get my data out.  ;(

Comment: Your million dollar question: by calling `[dataObject addItemObject:itemObject]` for each case, you have established a similar link as the correspondence with code. You can repeat this scheme with as many entities as you like, just by establishing more relationships.

Comment: Since you have answered the question but I still have a whole in my understanding.

Comment: If my Data Entity matches my Data table in mysql... its one to one... 
So when I am looping through my rows in and putting in one row as an object into an entity and then I have to get the corresponding row for that row and create the objects this way???  
The Item table is like a master table and there is a bunch of rows/objects that are not related to the data table in any way.

Comment: Say your saying if I make my objects in this way that I won't even have to perform any type of predicates?>? That core data will just know that there is a relationship that connects those two when I entered the data and then .... ahhh I see.

Comment: You have to generate the class files (Xcode xcdatamodel editor, select the entities, choose menu  Editor --> Create NSManagedObject Sublcass... Xcode will generate these methods for you (look at the new Data.h).

Comment: Yeah I get what your saying now.... I just have to do some much more work to get my data imported properly..... and it will take longer now as I basically have to ------
Iterate over every row to check a match for data.item == item.code than make sure those rows are related before I put them in core data.  Once it is done though it will be a snap to get the data out..... Just a tradeoff I guess. ;(

Comment: Which is why I was trying to get a shortcut out of trying to do it this way.

Comment: I wanted to do this via core data after the fact but I guess its just not possible.

Comment: So now basically I am making a special case for every table that has a relationship and have those tables imported as special cases the other tables that didn't use joins in the php code can be imported as is without building relationships.

Comment: Yep, that is the way to do it.

Comment: Well Thanks for the help I was just being hard headed.